# Cleaner method for finding the shortest distance between points in a python list?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, distance, heuristics

I have a list of tuples and an individual point in python e.g. [(1,2) , (2,5), (6,7), (9,3)] and (2,1) , and I want to figure out the fastest path possible created by all combinations of the individual point to the list of points.(Basically I want to find the most efficient way to get to all of the points starting from (2,1)). I have a manhattanDistance function that can take it 2 points and output the distance. However, my algorithm is giving me inconsistent answers (The heuristic is off for some reason)

What would be the correct way to accomplish this?

Here is my previous algorithm:

```
def bestPath(currentPoint,goalList):
    sum = 0
    bestList = []
    while len(goallist) > 0:
        for point in list:
            bestList.append((manhattanD(point,currentPoint),point))
        bestTup = min(bestList)
        bestList = []
        dist = bestTup[0]
        newP = bestTup[1]
        currentPoint = newP
        sum += dist
return sum
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the function?

Comment: Are you aware that this is the [Travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)?

Comment: Is it the traveling salesman problem? I thought it had more to do with finding all possible combinations of paths and then taking the best one.

Comment: _italic_Is it the traveling salesman problem? I thought it had more to do with finding all possible combinations of paths and then taking the best one_italic_

Isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: Yes. You are right actually, this might be the traveling salesman problem.

Comment: Do you want to know the shortest path between the start and each points, or do you want to know the shortest path that contains all the points?

Comment: `while len(list)` .... which list?

Comment: The shortest path containing all points. The len(list) should be len(goalList)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have so many point, you can easily use a solution that try every possibility.

Here is what you can do:

First get all combinations:

```
>>> list_of_points = [(1,2) , (2,5), (6,7), (9,3)]
>>> list(itertools.permutations(list_of_points))
[((1, 2), (2, 5), (6, 7), (9, 3)),
((1, 2), (2, 5), (9, 3), (6, 7)),
((1, 2), (6, 7), (2, 5), (9, 3)),
((1, 2), (6, 7), (9, 3), (2, 5)),
((1, 2), (9, 3), (2, 5), (6, 7)),
((1, 2), (9, 3), (6, 7), (2, 5)),
((2, 5), (1, 2), (6, 7), (9, 3)),
((2, 5), (1, 2), (9, 3), (6, 7)),
((2, 5), (6, 7), (1, 2), (9, 3)),
((2, 5), (6, 7), (9, 3), (1, 2)),
((2, 5), (9, 3), (1, 2), (6, 7)),
((2, 5), (9, 3), (6, 7), (1, 2)),
((6, 7), (1, 2), (2, 5), (9, 3)),
((6, 7), (1, 2), (9, 3), (2, 5)),
((6, 7), (2, 5), (1, 2), (9, 3)),
((6, 7), (2, 5), (9, 3), (1, 2)),
((6, 7), (9, 3), (1, 2), (2, 5)),
((6, 7), (9, 3), (2, 5), (1, 2)),
((9, 3), (1, 2), (2, 5), (6, 7)),
((9, 3), (1, 2), (6, 7), (2, 5)),
((9, 3), (2, 5), (1, 2), (6, 7)),
((9, 3), (2, 5), (6, 7), (1, 2)),
((9, 3), (6, 7), (1, 2), (2, 5)),
((9, 3), (6, 7), (2, 5), (1, 2))]
```

Then create a function that give you the length of a combination:

```
def combination_length(start_point, combination):
    lenght = 0
    previous = start_point  
    for elem in combination:
        lenght += manhattanDistance(previous, elem)

    return length
```

Finally a function that test every possibility:

```
def get_shortest_path(start_point, list_of_point):
    min = sys.maxint
    combination_min = None
    list_of_combinations = list(itertools.permutations(list_of_points))
    for combination in list_of_combination:
        length = combination_length(start_point, combination)
        if length < min:
            min = length
            combination_min = combination

    return combination_min
```

Then finally you can have:

```
import sys, itertools

def combination_length(start_point, combination):
    lenght = 0
    previous = start_point  
    for elem in combination:
        lenght += manhattanDistance(previous, elem)

    return length

def get_shortest_path(start_point, list_of_point):
    min = sys.maxint
    combination_min = None
    list_of_combinations = list(itertools.permutations(list_of_points))
    for combination in list_of_combination:
        length = combination_length(start_point, combination)
        if length < min:
            min = length
            combination_min = combination

    return combination_min

list_of_points = [(1,2) , (2,5), (6,7), (9,3)]
print get_shortest_path((2,1), list_of_points)
```

Comment: You have to be conscious that this is not exactly the salesman problem as this solution doesn't take into the length to come back to the start point.
That will need a minor change, but I don't think that it is what you need when I read your question.

Comment: Thank you. This should work, since the lists are small. I do not need to come back fortunately, so this should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If this is anything like the traveling salesman problem, then you want to check out the [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) python module.

Answer (score -1):

Try to find all combination, then check the shortest distance.